# Put several plots into exactly the space of one plot

Tags: r, plot

I have all the parameters fixed to describe one plot including `oma`, `mar`, `mgp`, ... I want to divide the very plot area into several separate, exactly equally sized smaller plot areas which share both x and y label. For example something like this:

[image: Three plots in one]

I found solutions to combine plots but with seperate axes. Any starting point for the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the outer margins to be big enough to hold the axes and labels, then set the regular margins to 0.  Use `par(mfrow` or `layout` to split the inner region into the panels that you want, then do the plots without the axes and labels and add the axes and labels into the outer margins:

```
par( oma=c(5,4,4,1)+0.1, mar=c(0,0,0,0) )
layout( matrix( 1:3, nrow=1 ) )
for( i in levels(iris$Species) ) {
    with( iris[ iris$Species==i, ], {
        plot(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, ann=FALSE, xaxt='n', yaxt='n',
            ylim=range(iris$Sepal.Length))
        axis(1, outer=TRUE)
        mtext(side=3, i ) }
    )
}
axis(2, outer=TRUE)
```

But it is probably simpler using lattice or ggplot2.

Comment: Thanks! That way I have exactly the style of the basic R plots. I used ``mfrow`` and for me it was important to set ``cex=1.`` so that all distances correspond to my default settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at using ggplot2 to see if there is a solution there that meets your needs.  I find the plot you linked to be visually confusing.

Comment: I very much would like to use the R standard graphics system because I have used this for everything else. In the real plot, the three lines are much closer together in every subplot. It is relatively easy to see that they belong together. (The original plot is from a publication of mine which I had to change for using here.)

Comment: Looking at ggplot2, the facit grid seems to be what I want. However, the ggplot2 style seems to be quite different than the normal R style.

Comment: The style is customizable, but I think many folks find the ggplot2 defaults quite appealing.